# Selenium Dropdown menu как кнопка

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Доброго дня!
Есть сайт, написанный на ангуляре.
В нем есть кнопка выбора пола. Мне нужно выбрать значение по тексту\индексу. 
К сожалению, не знаю как это сделать.

При попытке выбрать как Select пишет, что "Element should have been "select" but was "button"

[image: code]

Comment: покажите как вы хотите выбрать

Comment: Сейчас я выбираю по-тупому
`driver.findelement(By.xpath(locator)).click();
     driver.findelement(By.linkText("Мужской").click();
`

Comment: вам нужно кликнуть, чтобы она раскрылась, потом у раскрывшиеся списка найти By и после этого написать метод перебора этих значений и выбора

Comment: вы можете дать адрес сайта? либо раскройте список select и приложите к ответу как текст

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. это всего лишь кнопка по нажатию на которую, вероятно, происходит какая-то анимация, то алгоритм работы должен быть примерно следующим:

1. Кликнуть на кнопку;
2. Дождаться отрисовки блока выпадающего списка;
3. Найти нужный элемент в этом блоке и произвести с ним действие